# How to start Access from Commandline in regular mode

Tags: excel, vba, shell, ms-access, command-line

I have an update routine that involves various different procedures that runs during the night. The procedures are all stored in an excel file which calls them in the order needed using commandline.

Now I need to add an Access Database File that is to be included. I can open the Access Database and the file I want, but only in "Read only" mode. It also doesn't recognize the Macro I am calling either.

**My commandline looks like this:**

```
MSACCESS.EXE /ro "W:\Mandate.accdb" /x AutoRunProcess
```

**Problem 1:How do you open an access file in regular mode?** I have researched the topic a bit and have looked at Microsofts documentation, but found no information about how to open a database so you can run updates and save it again. The examples provided are only for opening in "read-only" mode [source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Access-558cfe1d-3c98-4292-bee8-1f5df9702bf1).

**Problem 2: Macro not found** Though my current code opens the correct access database file, it says it can't find the macro. However, the macro runs fine if I start it manually.

Any pointers or help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but to **not** open the database read-only, **don't** specify the `/ro` switch. Being read-only may also cause not running the macro.

Comment: "/ro" stands for "read only". go figure. i took it out. the read only problem is solved. thank you! macros are still not running though.

Comment: i have also tried refrencing the macro with the module name like this: `modAutoRun.AutoRunProcess` unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Also tested to no avail:`MSACCESS.EXE "W:\Mandate.accdb" /x "AutoRunProcess"`

Comment: the problem seems to be in Access itself... it won't recognize the Macro. I can't get it to run from AutoExec either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:
To **not** open the database read-only, **don't** specify the `/ro` switch. :)

Problem 2:
A general suggestion is to avoid macros as far as possible. Generally, a database should have **one** macro, that is `AutoExec`.

Although with a quick test the /x switch worked for me, even if the database has a `AutoExec` macro. `AutoExec` runs first, then the /x macro.

An alternative is the `/cmd` switch. You pass a string that you read in your AutoExec function with the `Command()` function.

```vb
Select Case Command()
    Case "AutoRunProcess": Call MyProcess
    Case "SomethingElse": Call AnotherFunction
    Case "": ' nothing was passed in /cmd
    Case Else: MsgBox "Error in command-line: " & Command()
End Select
```

Comment: I tried the `/cmd` switch as well, but it also didn't work for me. I just finished finding a solution... which is the `AutoExec`. I took me a bit to learn that this needs to be a Function. Possibly this could also have been the error from the commandline. Haven't tried that variation yet. Thank you for your help!